# Bypass authorisation for url with query parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, url, spring-security

I have spring security and JWT auth in my project. Hence there is class WebSecurityConfig.java that has below method that allows some APIs to be permitted without authorization

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity, JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint,
                                           JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .exceptionHandling(configurer -> configurer
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                .sessionManagement(configurer -> configurer
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize.requestMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/get-is-account-locked").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/*").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated());

     
        if (sslEnable) {
            httpSecurity.requiresChannel(channelRequestMatcherRegistry -> channelRequestMatcherRegistry.anyRequest().requiresSecure());
        }

       
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UserPasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
```

As you can see, /authenticate and /get-is-account-locked apis we are bypassing it without authorization, that means when these api are hit, no authorization is needed.

I want to allow one more api without authorization but the problem is it should skip authorization only when it has query parameters with specific values.

Example
http://localhost:8080/legendary?type=system&name=sigma

So i thought i can include it as `.requestMatchers("legendary?type=system&name=sigma").permitAll()`
but that did not work, it still needed authorization for this URL.

I assume it did not work due to query parameters. Can someone help as how to skip authorization / permit this api without authorization when url ends up exactly like above with those query param values?

Comment: what does your `jwtRequestFilter` do, because you do know that handing out JWTs to browsers is not recommended, using JWTs as sessions is also not recommended, thats why there is no implementation for it in spring security. So why have you built something that is not recommended and not defined in the spring security docs. Why havnt you read the docs?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using path variables instead.
Your controller will be like this:

```
@GetMapping("/legendary/{type}/{name}")
public String api(@PathVariable String type, @PathVariable String name) {
    return "OK!!!";
}
```

and your security config will be like this:

```
.requestMatchers("/legendary/system/sigma").permitAll()
```

But if you want to do this by query param I think you should handle it in your controller and check parameters value if they don't match you should throw an exception.